# Draw Line Dynamically on mouse move GDI C#

Tags: c#, graphics, line, gdi

I have a graphics program which is a simple basic shapes(lines,circle,rectangle) drawing.I have a line class. The line is drawn on bitmap which is painted on panel. I have two line lists(Lines,Lines are added to it, DelLines,Line in this list are not drawn in Paint Event) to which every drawn line is added. Then in paint event the invalidation causes the drawn lines list to draw on panel. There is no problem when i click without using mouse move. What i get is [image]

```
class Line
{
    public float width { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }

    public Line(Color col, float w, Point s, Point e)
    {
        color = col;
        Start = s;
        End = e;
        width = w;
    }
    public void Draw(Graphics G)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(color, width))
        {
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            G.DrawLine(pen, Start, End);

        }
    }
    public bool SelectLine(Point Pt)
    {
        if ((Pt.X < Start.X && Pt.X < End.X) || (Pt.X > Start.X && Pt.X > End.X) ||
 (Pt.Y < Start.Y && Pt.Y < End.Y) || (Pt.Y > Start.Y && Pt.Y > End.Y))

            return false;
        // now we calculate the distance:
        float dy = End.Y - Start.Y;
        float dx = End.X - Start.X;
        float Z = dy * Pt.X - dx * Pt.Y + Start.Y * End.X - Start.X * End.Y;
        float N = dy * dy + dx * dx;
        float dist = (float)(Math.Abs(Z) / Math.Sqrt(N));
        // done:
        return dist < width / 2f;

    }
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap);
        if (snap == true)
        {
            SnapToGrid(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }

        //Cursor Location
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Translate(panel1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2);
        m.Invert();
        System.Drawing.Point[] pa = new System.Drawing.Point[] { new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y) };
        m.TransformPoints(pa);
        lbl_x.Text = pa[0].ToString().Substring(1, pa[0].ToString().Length - 2);
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (leftdown)
        {
            Point p = PointsList[0];

            //Line
            Line line = new Line(Color.White, 2, p, e.Location);
            line.Draw(g);

            Lines.Add(line);

            if (Lines.Count > 0)
            {
                                    DelLines.Add(line);
```

I also tried Lines.RemoveAt(Lines.Count-1) giving same result.

```
            }

            //Distance
            double dst = Math.Abs(((p.X - e.X) + (p.Y - e.Y))); 

            //Angle
            double angle = Math.Atan2(e.Y - p.Y, e.X - p.X);
            angle = Math.Round((angle * 180) / Math.PI, 0);

            Label label = new Label();
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(label);
            label.Location = e.Location;
            label.Text = dst.ToString() + "@" + angle.ToString() + "°";
            List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();
            Labels.Add(label);

            if (Labels.Count > 0)
            {
                this.panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(Labels.Count-1);

            }
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }

    }
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)// On mouse down
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        if (dist == false && circ == false) //Distance Measure and Circle Drawing not initiated
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                leftdown = true;
                count++;
                Dot dot = new Dot(e.X, e.Y, 2, 2, Color.White,e.Location);
                Dots.Add(dot);
                dot.DrawPoint(g);
                panel1.Invalidate();
                PointsList.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y)); //Add points on each click
                PointF[] pts = new PointF[] { new PointF(e.X, e.Y) };
                gp.AddLines(pts);
                if (PointsList.Count > 1)
                {
                    //  DrawLineP(PointsList[PointsList.Count - 2].X, PointsList[PointsList.Count - 2].Y, e.X, e.Y);

                  //  Line line = new Line(Color.White, 2, new Point(PointsList[PointsList.Count - 2].X, PointsList[PointsList.Count - 2].Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                   // Lines.Add(line);

                }

            }
            else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                foreach (Line line in Lines)
                {
                    line.color = line.SelectLine(e.Location) ? Color.Red : Color.White;

                    panel1.Invalidate();
                }

            }
        }
        else if (dist == true && circ == false)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                DsP1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y); //First point of Distance Measure
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(DsP1, new Size(1, 1)));
                label9.Font = font4;
                label10.Font = font3;
                g.DrawRectangle(RPen, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1));
            }
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(e.Location);

                DsP2 = new Point(e.X, e.Y); //Second Point of Distance Measure
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(DsP2, new Size(1, 1)));

                double x = DsP1.X - DsP2.X;
                double y = DsP1.Y - DsP2.Y;
                double d = Math.Abs(x + y);
                float midX = (DsP1.X + DsP2.X) / 2;
                float midY = (DsP1.Y + DsP2.Y) / 2;
                DrawDist(DsP1, DsP2, d, midX, midY, Color.White); //Method
            }

        }
        if (circ == true && dist == false) //Circle Drawing
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {

                PointsList.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y)); //Add points on each click

                if (PointsList.Count > 1)
                {
                    DsP1 = PointsList[0];
                    DsP2 = PointsList[1];
                    // DrawCirc(DsP1, DsP2, Color.White); //Method
                    Circle circle = new Circle(Color.White, 2, DsP1, (DsP2.Y - DsP1.Y));
                    Circles.Add(circle);
                    PointsList.Clear();
                    circ = false;
                    panel1.Invalidate();
                }


            }

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                foreach (Circle circle in Circles)
                {
                    circle.color= circle.SelectCircle(e.Location) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
                    panel1.Invalidate();
                }

            }

        }


        //Angle Measurement
        if (angle_select == true || fillet==true)
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    foreach (Line line in Lines)
                    {
                        if (line.color == Color.Red)
                        {
                            AngL1P1 = line.Start;
                            AngL1P2 = line.End;
                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    foreach (Line line in Lines)
                    {
                        if (line.color == Color.Red)
                        {
                            AngL2P1 = line.Start;
                            AngL2P2 = line.End;
                            count = 0;
                            angle_select = false;
                            AngleMeasure(g);
                            panel1.Invalidate();
                            panel1.Cursor = this.Cursor;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics grp = e.Graphics;

        grp.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        grp.DrawImage(Bitmap, panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y - 158);

        DrawPolygon(grp);
        DrawAxes();
        DrawGrid();
        foreach (Line L in Lines.Except(DelLines))
        {
            L.Draw(grp);
        }
        foreach(Circle C in Circles)
        {
            C.Draw(grp);
        }
        foreach(Dot p in Dots)
        {
            p.DrawPoint(grp);
        }
        grp.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to draw the line on mouse move, so that it shows the the line drawn from start click and current position of cursor. Not the previous lines.
Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When drawing a new element, just draw **that element** using the supplied Graphics for the Paint() event.  The stuff in the Bitmap doesn't need to change for a new element.  Once the new element has been finalized (user releases mouse), then update the Bitmap with the new element.  Since you are drawing the new element with the Graphics in the Paint() event, it will be erased for you when the panel is invalidated.  Make a separate method that generates the bitmap and only call that when the Bitmap has **CHANGED**, don't call it for every Paint() event!

Comment: Thats great Thanks. The problem is i hardly see any thing. When i move mouse, i can hardly see 10% of time the line. I will stick with stationary mode. What i did is put a label on top which is updates the distance from point and angle with respect to horizental. Thanks again i appreciate it

Comment: I would need to see a video of what is happening and maybe have a test project to play with to really help you out.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=139sZpmbWz7j9ZBezlmWj6rwE8NrXi61Q)

Comment: So i was looking if i can do snap to grid or enable Ortho mode. But as i can't see the line as i draw with mouse, snapping is useless.